# Including .htaccess in apache2.conf with 'AllowOverride None' slows down Apache?

Tags: performance, apache, .htaccess, apache2, httpd.conf

> If you have access to the main server configuration file (usually called `httpd.conf`), you should add the logic from the `.htaccess` file in, for example, a `<Directory>` section in the main configuration file. This is usually the recommended way, as using `.htaccess` files slows down Apache! ([Source](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/README.md#apache-server-configs))

I think it essentially means, if possible, I should `Include httpd.conf` along with the `AllowOverride None` directive in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

But semantics (or whatever) aside, why can't I simply include `.htaccess` itself? For my convenience I am doing it like this...

***File:*** /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
#
# [... ORIGINAL CONTENTS OF APACHE2.CONF ...]
#


<Directory /var/www/example.com/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride None
    Include /var/www/example.com/public/.htaccess
</Directory>
```

With the `.htaccess` file included in `apache2.conf`, and the `AllowOverride None` directive in place, I can simply add all my site's rewrite rules in `/var/www/example.com/public/.htaccess`.

If need to use another .htaccess file for another sub-directory, I simply add another `Include` for the new `.htaccess` file in `apache2.conf` just the way I am doing it now.

**My question is,** is this just as performant as using `httpd.conf`? (I believe [I was told otherwise here](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/issues/1#issuecomment-45844813), which is why I am asking.) If not, why not?

---

**Reason why I prefer using .htaccess:** My server runs WordPress, and some WordPress plugins I use (SEO, caching, etc.) add rewrite rules in .htaccess files. By using .htaccess I don't have to do this manually myself, and can simply let the plugins do their job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the same runtime performance as putting it directly in httpd.conf. The operative part is that it's parsed at startup, not while mapping a request to the filesystem and checking for htaccess and interpreting it each time.